# How to filter and count percentages and count in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

After a query I end up with a table like this
   `tbl_1`:

```
 category type   count
    cpg      b      1
    auto     c      1
    cpg      c      1
    auto     v      1
```

I would like to calculate the total_count by `category`, and the percentage of count that **is not** (`type<>'v'`) also by category in SQL.

Any ideas how I could do that ?

The resulting table should look like this:

```
category total_count percentage
cpg          2         1
auto         2         0.5
```

Comment: Please show the results that you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you want?

```
select category, sum(count),
       sum(case when  type <> 'v' then count else 0.0 end) / sum(count)
from t
group by category;
```

From the original table, you could just do:

```
select category, count(*) as cnt,
       avg(case when type <> 'v' then 1.0 else 0 end) as ratio
from tbl1
group by category;
```